# summing positive and negative numbers in MapReduce Iterable IntWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using MapReduce in Java Hadoop to calculate the difference between the outgoing edges and incoming edges.
For instance node 2 has 2 outgoing edges and 3 incoming edges, then the difference is -1.

src, tgt

1,  **2**
**2**,  1
**2**,  3
3,  **2**
 
4,  **2**
4,  3

So the output should be: node 2, difference: -1.

In the Mapper function I assigned the IntWritable +1 if 2 is the source and -1 if 2 is the target.

so the mapper is producing this following Iterable IntWritable and sending it to the Reducer.

(node 2, values( -1, +1, +1, -1, -1)) and the reducer is returning (0, -1) instead of just -1.

Output below:

1    0
**2**    0
**2**   -1
3    0
3   -1
4    2

I tried it several times with different scenarios and that's what I believe is happening. I don't how to get the reducer to simply add all numbers and return one value??

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: It was solved. the problem was unseen characters in the text document. So -1 in one row was not the same as -1 in the other row.